# Git commit fails because lint is required

Tags: git

I have a project that has aframe in the source which is included in the package as such

```
"aframe": "git+https://github.com/aframevr/aframe.git",
```

When I try and commit the project, I get this error:

```
husky - pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
> git config --get-all user.name
> git config --get-all user.email
> git show :.gitignore
> git add -A -- .
> git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -

> aframe@0.9.2 precommit /home/owner/workspace/client/node_modules/aframe
> npm run lint


> aframe@0.9.2 lint /home/owner/workspace/client/node_modules/aframe
> semistandard -v | snazzy

sh: 1: semistandard: not found
sh: 1: snazzy: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! aframe@0.9.2 lint: `semistandard -v | snazzy`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the aframe@0.9.2 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I don't want to commit anything from aframe, I havn't changed anything and gitignore should be ignoring everything in node_modules

```
node_modules/
node_modules/aframe
```

How can I get past this and just commit my code?

Comment: It tells you right in the error message.

Comment: I'm asking how to ignore this, I don't want to be running lint on aframe, none of this is required.

Comment: Why isn't .gitignore excluding this from node_modules?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm asking how to ignore this, I don't want to be running lint on aframe

If this is a precommit, and you want to bypass it, you can add the [-n option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--n):

```
git commit -n --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
```

That will prevent the hook to be triggered in that case (for that specific commit).

But if you need the hook for other files in your commits, you would need to make a smaller regular commit with just those files.

To disable that hook permanently, look for a `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file and rename it.

Comment: Thanks. How can I ignore this for just all commits, Aframe is just a library in node_modules, I've made no changes to it, I don't need to run this lint.

Comment: @beek I have edited the answer to add a way to disable that step.

Comment: Thanks mate. Some how every file in hooks mentions aframe. Aframe has somehow contaminated my git. How can I reset this>

Comment: @beek Check first if renaming that one hook allows you to move forward.